# Is there still a qgis plugin wishlist?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I was wondering if there is something like a wishlist for QGIS plugins?
The link on this [page](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#id2) does not work anymore. 
It would be quite useful to know what people need.

Answer (score 2):

There is a QGIS user poll wherein you could present your views: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfyVvCBjGCb3mtk9GbaAvw7fc5p54fvL6bg5JBl_nf0NfOvyw/viewform?formkey=dDA5TW96Z19aNFU1OVpzSzFyRzFybmc6MQ

And a Google Doc form where you can provide ideas or views on the built-in tools on QGIS: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CTjrXWu0EJqLWcKU2ifBoQKPwXlZAkZnSzewq8zsamM/edit?hl=en_US